# CSS file path is showing in model using ajax in php

Tags: html, css, ajax

```js
newFunction();

function newFunction() {
  const newLocal_1 = $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checking_email").keyup(function() {
      var email = $("#checking_email").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "code.php",
        data: {
          check_submit_btn: 1,
          email_id: email,
        },
        success: function(response) {
          $("#error_email").text(response);
        },
      });
    });
  });
  const newLocal = newLocal_1;
}
```

when I am using this javascript code everthing is working file except it is showing my css file path with the message in the form model [this img shown my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l23iT.png)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $("#error_email").text(response);
> ```

The text method treats the input as text and converts it to DOM.

If you want HTML to be treated as HTML and not plain text, use the `html()` method.

---

That said, it is often better to return data formatted as JSON and generate the HTML or DOM for it client side.

Dynamically adding `<link>` elements to load additional CSS as a side effect of displaying a message sounds like a recipe for trouble.

Comment: Thank you for helping me but i Tried html() method but this is not help me to solve the problem